# i am not able to understand how props works in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have written a component counter in a module named counter.jsx and now I am trying to import that component(counter) in a new module counter .jsx and using it four times in counters.jsx. now when I tried to print props in counters.jsx render method it is getting printed twice for every  component . **so it is printing props object 8 times on console for four components.why is it printing 8 times, can anyone explain me please**

**counter.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {

    state = {count:0,
             tags : ['tag1','tag2','tag3'],
             tagObj : {'tag1':1 , 'tag2':2},
             id:5

    };

    //User-def Functions

    h=5;

    formatCount()
    {
        if(this.state.count === 0)
        {
            return 'Zero';
        }
        else
        {
            return this.state.count;
        }

    }

    // how to use map functions
    renderList()
    {
        const List = this.state.tags.map( (tag) =>  <li key={tag} > <a href='/'>{tag}</a> </li>  );
        return (List.length===0)?<p>shopping cart is empty</p>: List ;
    }


    getBadgeClassess()
    {
        var classes = 'badge m-2 badge-';
        classes += (this.state.count === 0) ? "warning" : "primary";
        return classes;
    }

     handleCountIncrement = () => {

        //  console.log(incr);
         this.setState( { count: this.state.count + 1 });
     }

    // Render Function
    render() { 

        console.log("props" , this.props);
        return(
                //  <React.Fragment>
                <div>                     
                    <span className={this.getBadgeClassess()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
                    <button onClick={ this.handleCountIncrement  } className='btn btn-primary btn-sm' >Increment</button>

                     {/* <ul> */}
                        {/* { this.state.tags.map( tag => <li>{ tag }</li>) } */}
                        {/* {this.renderList()} */}
                     {/* </ul> */}

                </div>

                // </React.Fragment> 
              );


        }
}

export default Counter;
```

***counters.jsx***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Counter from './counter';


class Counters extends Component {
    state = { 
       counters : [ 
           { id:1 , value:0 },
           { id:2 , value:0 },
           { id:3 , value:0 },
           { id:4 , value:0 }
        ]
     }

    //  renderCounters = () =>{

    //  }


    render() { 

        console.log("props" , this.props);
        return ( 
            <div>

                {this.state.counters.map( (counter) => ( <Counter key={counter.id} selected={true} />) ) }

            </div>
         );
    }
}

export default Counters;
```

***on console***

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNcQ6.png)

Comment: See react lifecycle.

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox on https://codesandbox.io and share, it would be easier to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React is going to call render several times even if you render the component once, you can't control that. If you want to have certain control then you need to use the lifecycle methods:

https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_lifecycle.asp

Comment: I have seen my instructor's code there were exactly 4 calls there

Comment: even its printing values of propstwo times for every <counter /> call